# CodeIgniter URL parsing incorrectly

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a code igniter site which I have enabled some special characters so that characters such as £ can be used in the URL:

EG:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/products/details/Product-name-£
```

When I click on the URL, it tries to take me to the product page and then redirects me back to the homepage. On inspection of the site during the load, the request shows:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/products/details/Product-name-%C2%A3
```

I am assuming that this is obviously failing on the DB lookup which is why it is sending me back to the homepage.

Can anybody point me in the right direct as to where I can fix this? im guessing there needs to be some sort of conversion on the fly when its processed to make it readable, however i'm quite new to this code igniter site and im struggling to locate the best place to fix it?

Can anybody help?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do that

```
$var = urlencode($dbvalue);//var would be url safe
```

when you get the data back just do this

```
$var = utf8_decode(urldecode($_GET['val']));
```

give this var value to the database hopefully it would be fine.

Comment: Hi @Faiz thanks for your rapid response. You helped me yesterday with the strange character problem with £ displaying incorrectly. I am assuming I would make these changes in the model file or would I need to do it in the view/controller?

Comment: i think the easy way is to change in the controller where you receive the get variables.

Comment: Can you show us your controller where you receiving the get value

Comment: utf8_decode(urldecode($_GET['val'])) worked perfectly! Now I feel stupid! Thanks @Faiz Rasool

Comment: Rascool I don't suppose you know how to get passed the issues with CI not allowing ' (apostrophe's) in URL's? at the moment, it passes /product-nam\'s and I get the Disallowed character error. However I have added the ' to teh Input.php  _clean_input_keys function but no joy :( Or can you just not has them in URL's?